# Angularjs ui router go to same state with different params

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router

I am using angularjs ui router for my cordova application. I am able to go to a particular state (say state 'x') with params. But when I am in state 'x', and pass different parameters I am not able to see the new data.

This is the current url `file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/x/25` and I am trying to go to `file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/x/30`, but I still see the same data of `file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/x/25`.

I tried to use

```
$state.go('^.x', {param: value});

$state.go('x', {param: value}, {reload: true});
```

But none of the above code works.

Comment: Got any solution for the above issue ? I m facing same too.

Comment: @UmakantaBehera I have posted the answe, check if it works!

Answer (score 0):

I changed my state definition by defining the state parameters with default null value.

```
.state('state_name', {
  url: '/state_name/:paramId',
  templateUrl: 'templates/state_name.html',
  controller: 'state_nameCtrl',
  params: {
    'paramId': null,
  }
})
```

Hope this helps!